# Any map of a contractible complex to itself has a fixed point

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, reference-request

Reading [Lovasz's lecture notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0205031) on evasive graph properties, I encountered the following extension of Brouwer's fixed point theorem:

**Any continues map from a contractible [finite] simplicial complex to itself has a fixed point.**

Lovasz refers this to Lefschetz. Indeed, it seems [Lefschetz fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem) guarantees the existence of a fixed point under some conditions. 
But I could not find a simple proof for Lefschetz theorem, while Brouwer's theorem has an elementary proof using Sperner's Lemma.

My questions are:

1. How should one interpret the conditions of Lefschetz fixed-point theorem,
   and why do they hold for a contractible complex?
   (A good reference will be appreciated.)
2. Is there an easy way to prove the above
   statement, for the restricted case
   of a collapsible complex, and a
   simplicial, bijective map,
   without using homology?

Comment: You must assume your complex is finite; otherwise consider a translation of the real line.

Comment: Indeed, the complex must be finite. Thanks.

Comment: @Tom Church: In fact you do not need finiteness, a weaker condition of being rayless suffices. See the paper: V. Okhezin, "On the fixed-point theory for non-compact maps and spaces. I", Topological Methods in Nonlinear Analysis 5 (1995), 83-100 ( http://www.tmna.ncu.pl/files/v05n1-05.pdf )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to assume that your complex is finite. Then the Lefschetz Fixed Point Theorem definitely says that $f$ must have a fixed point if the (homologically defined) Lefschetz number of $f$ is not zero. If the complex is contractible, then the Lefschetz number of $f$ must be $1$.

This fact about contractible complexes reduces to the Brouwer Theorem if you use the following fact: any finite contractible complex is a retract of $D^n$ for some $n$. That is, there exist continuous maps $i:X\to D^n$ and $r: D^n\to X$ such that $r\circ i$ is the identity. For continuous $f:X\to X$, any fixed point of $i\circ f\circ r:D^n\to D^n$ gives you a fixed point of $f$.

Comment: Thanks.
I assume the contractility of $X$ is used to prove that such $D^n$ and $r$ exist.
Could you give some guidelines for the proof of this fact?


Comment: I think that ENR, euclidean neighborhood retract, is the key phrase.

Comment: @Tom, I read about ENR, and indeed any finite complex is an ENR.
But this holds even if the complex is not contractible;
where do the contractibility goes into the picture?


Comment: Embed $X$ in $\mathbb R^n$. It's a retarct of a nbhd $N$. In $N$ is a smaller nbhd $K$ that is a union of cubes with edges parallel to the axes. $X$ is also a retarct of $K$. Now let $C$ be a cube containing $K$, and extend the retraction $K\to X$ to a map $C\to X$ (cell by cell) to get that $X$ is a retract of $C$.

Comment: @Tom, that's a nice construction!